# Outlook addin not installing in outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, add-in, office365, office365-apps, outlook-web-app

I have developed an office365 outlook add-in and pushed it to store. It passed the test and is now available at the store. They tested it and said it is working in Outlook 2013.

I have been using it in Outlook 2013 desktop client and is working fine.

Recently one of our clients added it and is working in OWA. But it is not showing up in Outlook 2013 desktop client.

Is there any different versions in Outlook 2013?. When I click on the File menu, I see "Manage Add-ins" at the bottom of account information. But the outlook 2013 he is using has the option "Manage Apps".

Comment: Does your client use an Exchange account?

Comment: What happens when your customer clicks on "Manage Apps"? Does he get taken to the options page where he can manage the installed add-ins?

Does your customer see any of the default add-ins appearing (eg if he enters an address like "1 Microsoft Way, Redmond WA, 98052", will bing maps add-in appear in Outlook)? Do any other add-ins work in Outlook for him?

what version of Outlook is he running (can see this by clicking on File -> Office Account)?

Comment: I don't think other add-ins are working for him. Normally when we compose a mail, we will see "Apps for Office" in ribbon. But that option is not showing up in his outlook.                                                                                                                                                                                                                           @Eugene yes, he's using the same account he's using in OWA.

Comment: What Outlook version does your client have installed on the PC (including build numbers)? Is it the Click2Run edition of Office?

Comment: @eugene so, is there are any outlook 2013 versions does not support add-in?. I like to know which versions support and which won't. That way we can mention it in our add-in description and will be useful for all who are going to install the add-in.

Comment: Outlook 2013 and above supports add-ins. Is there a chance the user could uncheck the ribbon tab/controls in the Outlook settings?